# eZPublish & Twig trans filter : chinese translation

Tags: symfony, twig, translation, chinese-locale, ezpublish

I'm currently working on the translation aspect of an eZPublish5 website which will contain 4 languages : french, english, russian and chinese, with french as original language and locale fallback.

Translation of content in backend is working just fine but I'm struggling with translating template parts, which I have encapsulated in `{% trans %}` filters. I don't think it's directly related to a locale issue because `{% trans %}` tags are working with french, english and russian, but not in chinese.

To do so I used
`php ezpublish/console translation:update --output-format=xlf locale bundle --force` witch generated *messages.fr.xlf*, *messages.en.xlf*, and *messages.ru.xlf*.

When in chinese, if I dump the locale in twig using `{{ app.request.locale }}` I get **zh_TW** for result, so I generated a *messages.zh_TW.xlf*, without any result.

After a loooong web search regarding language codes of all sort, I started losing patience and generated :

- *messages.chi.xlf*
- *messages.chi-TW.xlf*
- *messages.cn.xlf*
- *messages.zh.xlf*
- *messages.zh-tw.xlf*
- *messages.zh_TW.xlf*

to no avail.
This project is my first with eZpublish and I my first multilanguage under the Twig/Symfony logic.

Some code to show language declaration:

```
//ezpublish/config/ezpublish.yml
ezpublish:
    system:
        chi:
            languages:
            - chi-TW
            - fre-FR
        session:
            name: eZSESSID
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo.
I found a solution to solve my problem, and I'm quite ashamed to share it here.

-------Huge Revelation !-------

```
$php app/console cache:clear
```

The first three language files had been created quite a while ago and cache had been cleared a lot since, so that's why these trans files were working. I cleared the cache and now everything is working just fine.
BTW the answer to my own question was : **messages.zh_TW.xlf**

Now I'm gonna hide myself for a while.